# Which lead should I buy for my DC power supply?

Tags: power-supply

I am just getting into some electronics projects and some of the op-amp ones require a negative DC input voltage.

I ordered the ENGINDOT MDC01 DC power supply which is a three-port device. It has +, -, and ground. I didn’t get a lead that fits the ground terminal with the package though and from what I understand, that common ground is needed to create the negative power supply.

[image]

I found some cables that look like they’ll work, but I don’t want to waste money. What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure that the op-amp projects require one of the power inputs to be lower than ground? Sometimes, you can use ground as the negative power input (or even as the positive power input). By "ground," I mean the ground conductor in your circuit, not the ground terminal on the power supply.

Comment: Just to address your concern about cables:  The terminals on that power supply are combination binding post and Banana jack.  The outer plastic part is a nut you can unscrew then use to secure a bare wire to the terminal.  The terminal post under the nut will also have a hole to poke a bare wire through.  The hole in the center of the terminal post will accept a banana plug.  That is a very common type of connector on test equipment.  You may use a test lead with banana plug, or any handy wire, to connect to those terminals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The supply you ordered is a single-output supply. DC power supplies behave like batteries: their output floats, not galvanically connected to protective earth. That's what the green GND terminal is: it connects directly to the PE terminal of the 3-prong power input plug. You'd connect e.g. (+) and (GND) together to have a supply that extends below the Earth potential, i.e. (-) is then below Earth.

In normal use, you would leave the (GND) terminal disconnected, and ground your circuit at only one point through the oscilloscope probe, or a function generator that feeds the circuit with a signal, etc. This avoids the problem of ground loops, when the circuit is connected to Earth via multiple paths in parallel.

To get bipolar supplies for op-amp circuits, you'd need to buy a separate supply and connect the (+) terminal of the supply you designate as negative output to the (-) terminal of the supply you designate to be positive. These connected (+)(-) terminals become the 0V common point.

You can also use virtual ground generator circuits - but those may be an extra layer of complication that you don't need when starting out.

I'd suggest you buy a second power supply - that'd be the cheapest.

Or you can buy a double-output power supply.

If you have the room, the HP 6225A supply, like [this one on eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/403709709252) may not be a bad idea. It's a linear supply, and fairly robust. It'd be nice if you could find someone in your area to help you fixing such eBay buys if needed. Even though the seller claims that the supply "works", it may work only marginally. But those models typically work well if they do work.

Comment: HP made good stuff. I got a used high-voltage supply (a 6525A) off Amazon, and despite being more than twice as old as I am, it's working perfectly and still even reasonably close to in tolerance. I bet that'll still be working, unless its former owner really abused it.

Answer (score 7):

You are not the first person to be confused by this. This is a single output supply. The output voltage shown on the display is between the + and - terminals. The GND jack is earth ground, you often don't want to connect it to your project. During troubleshooting you may want to connect a scope, and a scope is usually referenced to earth ground. Connecting two earth grounds can create a ground loop, something to avoid if possible.

[image]

Comment: Re *"you often don't want to connect it to your project"*: Perhaps [expand](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/629250/edit) a little bit in your answer? Risk of ruining test equipment? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written right now)

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be overcomplicating the issue. The easiest way to achieve a positive and negative power supply is to connect two standard 9V batteries in series. The middle connection becomes your "ground".

Alternatively - and somewhat ironically - it is fairly straightforward to use  an op-amp to generate a "virtual ground" approximately halfway between positive and negative of a standard power supply or battery.

[image: example]

Comment: Do be aware of the limitations of the virtual ground technique, though.

Comment: @Hearth: What kind of limits? Low current?

Comment: Typically, it's a sensible assumption that connecting bypass capacitors between the "ground" and supply rails etc. will work. With a virtual ground provided by an op-amp, all you'll do is progressively destabilize the output, and the more capacitance there is, the worse it'll be - the op-amp will likely get hot, and the virtual ground will be a sine wave. The op-amp would need to be compensated to deal with a capacitive load. An LM358 also doesn't have all that much drive capability...

Comment: @PeterMortensen What Kuba said, mostly.